# State-of-the-art spelling correction algorithms

Tags: nlp, orthography

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spell_checker)

> The most successful algorithm to date is Andrew Golding and Dan Roth's "Winnow-based spelling correction algorithm", published in 1999, which is able to recognize about 96% of context-sensitive spelling errors, in addition to ordinary non-word spelling errors.

Is this up-to-date? What if we limit to algorithms not covered by patents?

EDIT: After reading the papers on Winnow, it only seems to support distinguishing a limited number of *confusion sets*, which need to be chosen before training, and so can't serve for general spelling correction anyway.

Answer (score 3):

From an applicative point of view the following software solutions are quite popular:

- GNU Aspell (which replaces Ispell)
- [Hunspell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunspell), look at the quite impressive list of uses, including Apache Solr, Google Chrome, Firefox, etc.

Finally, [Enchant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enchant_%28software%29) is an interesting aggregator as it capable of having multiple backends loaded at once.